# What's the difference between GTA 5 on PS3 & 4

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online, version-differences

I am planning on purchase GTA V for my PS3 but I would like to know if there are any significant differences between the game on the PS3 & 4 and what they are. Also, will it have online multiplayer gameplay with other PS3 users as well as PS4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several differences between the previous generation and current generation copies of Grand Theft Auto V.

The biggest difference is obviously going to be that of the physical platform. You can expect to see a better quality of picture on the PlayStation 4, with less loading time. [Sony provide a video comparison of the two versions on their blog.](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2014/11/05/grand-theft-auto-v-ps3-to-ps4-comparison/)

Apart from that, the PlayStation 4 version offers extra features. As listed by [IGN](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/GTA_5_Xbox_One,_PS4_and_PC_Differences), Xbox One, PlayStation 4 and PC gamers all get extras, including:

- Full first-person compatability: Go first person at the touch of a button.
- Better aiming controls: Greater customisation on the use of auto-aim.
- The addition of new outfits and vehicles: Including a monkey outfit for completing a new side-mission, and the inclusion of classic GTA vehicles.
- Exclusive rewards for return players: Not really applicable if it is one or the other, but there are [certain rewards](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/10/28/returning-gta-5-players-on-ps4-xbox-one-and-pc-get-exclusive-content) available in the next-gen version, if you continue over from the previous-generation.
- New missions, with unlockable rewards ranging from a video filter to an underwater submarine.
- New vehicles, including the [Cheval Marshall](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Cheval_Marshall) monster truck, and the [Xero Blimp](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Xero_Blimp).
- Two new weapons; a [hatchet](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Hatchet), and a [rail gun](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Rail_Gun). The rail gun will also feature new challenges.
- New collectibles, with new rewards.
- Phone conversations inside a vehicle will play the caller dialogue through the speaker on the DualShock controller. This is just a gimmick, but it adds to the immersion.

Lastly, **online play will allow for up to 30 players on next-gen, and only 16 players, on last-gen.** You will not be able to play against PlayStation 3 players, on PlayStation 4. However, you are able to transfer your character across to the PlayStation 4 from PlayStation 3, making it far more accessible for your friends to upgrade, and continue playing from their original online character.

Comment: It should also be noted that Rockstar will no longer be releasing new Online content for the PS3 - so any new missions, cars, etc, will only ever be available on the PS4.